# An index-aware array intersection

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am looking for a method for array intersection that, unlike the ordinary `&` method, matches only those elements that are the same and have the same index in both arrays. E.g.:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"].intersect(["a", "b", "f", "d", "c"])
```

should return

```
["a", "b", "d"]
```

because all three exist in both arrays at the same indexes (0, 1 and 3), while `"c"` is excluded because it has different positions in two arrays (2 and 4):

```
# 0    1    2    3    4
["a", "b", "c", "d"]
["a", "b", "f", "d", "c"]
```

I can think of several solutions for this problem. First one is looping, another one is modifying arrays first to include their indexes in the elements, and then intersect using `&`. E.g.:

```
["a", "b", "c"] #=> ["0a", "1b", "2c"]
```

However, I was wondering if there exists a better method. I am looking for using it both with positive and negative indexes.

Comment: It is not much clear what you mean by "using it both with positive and negative indexes".

Comment: E.g., ["a", "b", "c", "d"] 'intersect' ["c", "d", "a", "c", "d"] shall return ["c", "d"], because in both arrays "d" is of -1 index, and "c" is of -2 index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your two arrays `a` and `b`:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
b = ["a", "b", "f", "d", "c"]
```

Here are different attempts:

#### Using `zip` and `select`

You can use [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) to combine the corresponding elements from both arrays and [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) to retrieve the equal ones:

```
a.zip(b).select { |x, y| x == y }.map(&:first)
#=> ["a", "b", "d"]
```

Step by step:

```
a.zip(b)                   #=> [["a", "a"], ["b", "b"], ["c", "f"], ["d", "d"]]
 .select { |x, y| x == y } #=> [["a", "a"], ["b", "b"], ["d", "d"]]
 .map(&:first)             #=> ["a", "b", "d"]
```

Note that `zip` fills the second array with `nil` values if it is shorter. This could be a problem if your arrays contain `nil` values:

```
a = [2, 1, nil]
b = [2]

a.zip(b).select { |x, y| x == y }.map(&:first)
#=> [2, nil]
```

This is because `b` becomes `[2, nil, nil]` within `zip`.

#### Using `each_with_index` and `&`

Or you could use [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) to build arrays of `[element, index]` pairs:

```
ai = a.each_with_index.to_a
#=> [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2], ["d", 3]]

bi = b.each_with_index.to_a
#=> [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["f", 2], ["d", 3], ["c", 4]]
```

and intersect them instead:

```
ai & bi
#=> [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["d", 3]]
```

We can use `map` to extract the first elements:

```
(ai & bi).map(&:first)
#=> ["a", "b", "d"]
```

In a single expression:

```
(a.each_with_index.to_a & b.each_with_index.to_a).map(&:first)
#=> ["a", "b", "d"]
```

#### Using `each_with_index` and `each_object`

Another way it to combine `each_with_index` and [`with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object):

```
a.each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(x, i), arr| arr << x if x == b[i] }
#=> ["a", "b", "d"]
```

Each element `x` in `a` is compared to the corresponding element in `b` and - if they are equal - added to the result array.

This avoids creating the intermediate arrays but I find it less readable.

#### Using a custom enumerator

`each_twin` might not be the best name (I'm bad at naming things):

```
def each_twin(a, b)
  return enum_for(__method__, a, b) unless block_given?
  loop do
    x, y = a.next, b.next
    yield x if x == y
  end
end

each_twin(a.to_enum, b.to_enum).to_a
#=> ["a", "b", "d"]
```

Within the loop, the next value is retrieved from both, `a` and `b`. The value from `a` is yielded if it is equal to `b`'s value. [`Enumerator#next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) causes the loop to exit when `a`'s or `b`'s end is reached.

Comment: `with_object([])` could just be `.map{ |x,i| x if x == b[i]}.compact` adds a bit to the readability and still avoids the intermediates.

Comment: @engineersmnky unless the arrays contain `nil` values. `compact` would remove these.

Comment: fair enough based on the simple use case provided I did not think that far into the situation `with_object` makes more sense in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
a1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
a2 = ["a", "b", "f", "d", "c"]

a1.each_index.with_object([]){|i, a| a.push(a1[i]) if a1[i] == a2[i]}
# => ["a", "b", "d"]
```

Comment: I like the symmetry in `a1[i] == a2[i]` and the fact that only two arguments are being passed to the block. Somehow, that looks a bit cleaner than my second attempt.

Comment: Perhaps `[a1.size, a2.size].min.times.with_object ([])...` in case `a1` contains a `nil`.